# WordPress permalink structure change re-direct htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I currently have a website using the permalink structure:

http://xxx.xxx/%postname%/

I want to change this to:

http://xxx.xxx/xxx/%postname%/

So basically giving the default post type a slug rewrite like you can with CPT.

However, as we all know all the indexed pages will 404 so I need to write some HTACCESS to but not sure what I need.

If I use the following then all pages are re-directed too:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/$ http://xxx.xxx/xxx/$1
```

Where as I just want the default post type re-directed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done, you need to completed 301 redirects for each post and tag.

Have blogged about my process here: http://www.chewx.co.uk/2015/wordpress-permalink-update-from-postname/

If anyone can think of a better way, let me know.